# Change video quality using HTML5 and JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, video

I am using HTML5 video player http://html5-ninja.com/preview/index/5 with ISM manifest taken from here http://playready.directtaps.net/smoothstreaming/.
Inside the manifest file there are quality levels :

```
 <StreamIndex Type="video" Name="video" Chunks="61" QualityLevels="8" MaxWidth="1280" MaxHeight="720" DisplayWidth="1280" DisplayHeight="720" Url="QualityLevels({bitrate})/Fragments(video={start time})">
<QualityLevel Index="0" Bitrate="2962000" FourCC="H264" MaxWidth="1280" MaxHeight="720" CodecPrivateData="000000016764001FAC2CA5014016EFFC100010014808080A000007D200017700C100005A648000B4C9FE31C6080002D3240005A64FF18E1DA12251600000000168E9093525"/>
<QualityLevel Index="1" Bitrate="2056000" FourCC="H264" MaxWidth="992" MaxHeight="560" CodecPrivateData="000000016764001FAC2CA503E047BFF040003FC52020202800001F480005DC03030003EBE8000FAFAFE31C6060007D7D0001F5F5FC6387684894580000000168E9093525"/>
<QualityLevel Index="2" Bitrate="1427000" FourCC="H264" MaxWidth="768" MaxHeight="432" CodecPrivateData="000000016764001EAC2CA50300DEFFC100010014808080A000007D200017700C0C000AE300002B8C7F8C718180015C600005718FF18E1DA12251600000000168E9093525"/>
<QualityLevel Index="3" Bitrate="991000" FourCC="H264" MaxWidth="592" MaxHeight="332" CodecPrivateData="0000000167640015AC2CA50250AFEFFF03FD0400520C0C0C800001F480005DC030200078F80003C7C7F8C71810003C7C0001E3E3FC6387684894580000000168E9093525"/>
<QualityLevel Index="4" Bitrate="688000" FourCC="H264" MaxWidth="448" MaxHeight="252" CodecPrivateData="0000000167640015AC2CA507021FBFFC1000100148303032000007D200017700C080014FF0000A7F8FE31C604000A7F800053FC7F18E1DA12251600000000168E9093525"/>
<QualityLevel Index="5" Bitrate="477000" FourCC="H264" MaxWidth="368" MaxHeight="208" CodecPrivateData="000000016764000DAC2CA505C6EFFC10000FED48303032000007D200017700C04003A3A0003A3A7F8C718080074740007474FF18E1DA1225160000000168E9093525"/>
<QualityLevel Index="6" Bitrate="331000" FourCC="H264" MaxWidth="284" MaxHeight="160" CodecPrivateData="000000016764000DAC2CA504857BFFF040003FE520C0C0C800001F480005DC0301000A198000A19FFE31C6020014330001433FFC6387684894580000000168E9093525"/>
<QualityLevel Index="7" Bitrate="230000" FourCC="H264" MaxWidth="224" MaxHeight="128" CodecPrivateData="000000016764000DAC2CA50E11BFF040003F0520C0C0C800001F480005DC0300001C1200038273F8C7180000E090001C139FC63876848945800000000168E9093525"/>
```

How can I change the quality of the video playing using JavaScript? I have no idea how to do this. I would be happy for any working example of quality changing also.

Comment: are you sure that this bootstrap-video-player supports smooth streaming? Seems to me like progressive download and not streaming player.

Comment: tested on sony smart TV, works fine.

Comment: What exactly did you test?

Answer (score 0):

According to https://www.h3xed.com/web-and-internet/how-youtube-determines-what-video-quality-to-play, at least on YouTube, the quality is selected automatically given the video size  on screen and the quality of the connection to the source.

Comment: I don't understand, how is this question related to youtube? Is youtube using this bootstrap-video-player or what? ))

Answer (score 0):

The way Adaptive Bit Rate streaming works is that the server provides a manifest with multiple different bit rates streams and the client selects the highest one it can based on the current network conditions and the capability of the devices.

The key point here is that it is the client that selects the bit rate.

In some clients you can override this manually (e.g. in YouTube under the settings button while watching a video).

The player you have linked does not appear to have an option to select the bit rate via Javascript.

If you take a look at the dashjs player (http://cdn.dashjs.org/latest/jsdoc/index.html) you can see it has some methods that allow you control the bit rate switching, for example (at http://cdn.dashjs.org/latest/jsdoc/module-MediaPlayer.html):

- setMaxAllowedBitrateFor(type, value)

It might be useful to play around with this to see if it meets your needs.

Comment: DASH is not Smoothstreaming. Or does DASH JS also support it?

Comment: There is an extension project to DashJS which supports smooth streaming: https://github.com/Orange-OpenSource/hasplayer.js. In case it is actually just the PlayReady DRM you need to support its worth noting that the DASH standard can support PlayReady DRM also via CENC (http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/WD-encrypted-media-20140828/cenc-format.html).